# Android webview with Iframe auto play pause video

Tags: android, youtube-iframe-api

I am using this [library](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/youtubetv) to play YouTube videos on android tv. Videos are playing fine. But when any user touch or click on a video it pauses and plays again on another click. I tried to make it not clickable:

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
});
mWebView.setClickable(false);
mWebView.setEnabled(false);
mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
mWebView.setFocusable(false);
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Layout file main_activity.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="it.tranvantung.stackoverflow.MainActivity">
    <fr.bmartel.youtubetv.YoutubeTvView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:yt_autoplay="true"
        app:yt_videoId="kjkTvbYvglQ" />
</LinearLayout>
```

2. My Activity: You can get `WebView` from `YoutubeTvView` and disable touch.

```js
    YoutubeTvView youtubeTvView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        youtubeTvView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_video);
        WebView youtubeWebview = youtubeTvView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youtubeWebview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

3. manifest file: Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

```js
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

4. build.gradle

`compile 'fr.bmartel:youtubetv:1.2'`

Comment: I edited my code. If it worked, upvote and accept, please!